# parse xml string in sas

Tags: xml, string, parsing, sas

In SAS I typically use a few nested commands to parse XML data strings into separate variables.

for example if I were trying to extract the value for "score" from an XML string I would use the following code.

```
var1 = put(compress(scan(substr(value,find(value,'<score>'),40),2,"><")),10.);
```

The code above works for extracting the first occurrence of  in the XML string but when I encounter this type of data string

```
<score>25</score><score>72</score><score>43</score>
```

the limitations of my code become clear. I am only able to extract the first iteration of  from my data set and I am not sure how to extract the second and third iteration of this parameter. How can I alter my code to tell SAS to take the data after the second and third iteration of my "score" parameter?

The above data is not fully representative of what I am working with. My own data may have as many as 40-80 characters between iterations of the  parameter.

Comment: Have you tried the SAS XML Mapper tool? Its included with Base SAS.

Answer (score 0):

XML parsing in SAS has many potential routes, depending on the particular XML file structure, desired results, and your capabilities.

If you can, construct an XML Map and use the XML Libname engine as your first option.  It's very powerful and very useful.  If you don't have the XML Mapper utility (freely distributed with most SAS installations, but if your_site doesn't install it then you may not) you can download it; the link for example for 9.2 is [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/engxml/62845/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002484837.htm); your particular version will have the same kind of page and link.  Or ask your SAS tech support rep.

If that's not possible for whatever reason, you could also create your own XML map; there are instructions on the web for doing that.  It uses XSL which is very powerful for mapping columns to datasets without having to find things manually.

If that doesn't work, then text parsing is possible in a number of ways.

First, your method above is probably the slowest, but does work (using FIND).  Some improvements include using SCAN and marking `"<>"` as delimiters.

Second, you can use `@"<score>"` named input; that's very powerful and lets you act as if `<score>` was your line/field delimiter basically.  You also in later versions of SAS can use `DLMSTR=` option in the filename and literally use it as your delimiter.

Third, you can use regular expressions.  `PRXMATCH` and the related will help here, as some of them are capable of iteratively searching (finding match 1, then match 2, then ...).  They're not perfect, but in limited situations they work fine.  They are somewhat difficult to learn, though, and I'm certainly not going to do a tutorial here.

I think in your above case the input method is simplest; see the following for example.

```
data test;
  input @"<score>" score 2. @@;
datalines;
<score>25</score><score>72</score><score>43</score> 
;;;;
run;
```

Obviously you can have some challenges still but this works in this particular example at least.